# Routing and Multiple view dones not show in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

HI i m try to show routing and multiple view in my anguar js code but there is not show can u please help me what is the problum and how to solve it.
Please Help me .

My Code it this

**HTML File Index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
    <title>New Page Angular</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angularjs-1_2_25-angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**App.js Code**

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', ['ngRoute', 'phonecatControllers']);


phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',

    function($routeProvider){

        $routeProvider.
            when('/phones', {
                templateUrl: 'phone-list.html',
                controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
            }).
            when('/phone/:phoneId', {
                templateUrl: 'phone-details.html',
                controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/phone'
            });
    }

    ]);
```

**Contrller .js code**

```
var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);

phonecatControllers.controller('phoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

        $http.get('phones.json').success(function(data){
            $scope.computers = data;
        });

}]);


    phonecatControllers.controller('phoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
         function($scope, $routeParams){

            $scope.phoneId = $routeParams.phoneId;

         }]);
```

**[To complete code is here Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fqVml1vtyGyKTKFdvHua?p=preview)**

Comment: Load ng-route's script as well, also you have a module depending on another, and are loading the dependency after loading the dependent module. Load the controllers file before app.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed 
 
in your index.html and you've got few spelling errors phones instead of phone ...

please see fixed version here  http://plnkr.co/edit/KwxKVgVpZXVEeLVQGBNn?p=preview

```
    var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', ['ngRoute']);


    phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',

        function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){

            $routeProvider.
                when('/phones', {
                    templateUrl: 'phone-list.html',
                    controller: 'phoneListCtrl'
                }).
                when('/phone/:phoneId', {
                    templateUrl: 'phone-detail.html',
                    controller: 'phoneDetailCtrl'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/phones'
                });
        }

        ]);

phonecatApp.controller('phoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

        $http.get('phones.json').success(function(data){
            $scope.computers = data;
        });

}]);


    phonecatApp.controller('phoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
         function($scope, $routeParams){


            $scope.phoneId = $routeParams.phoneId;

         }]);
```

Comment: @RohitAzad please see here http://www.thinkful.com/learn/angularjs-tutorial-build-a-gmail-clone/